# Merge two datasets using multiple column checks

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I do have two dataframes with one ID-Variable in the first df ("ID") and three in the second df ("SIC","Ur","Sonst"). Now I am trying to merge these two datasets by checking if the "ID" in the first df either matches with SIC, Ur, or Sonst in the respective row. Here is my reproducable example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C","D"),
                  Value=c(1:4))

df2 <- data.frame(SIC = c("B", NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  Ur = c(NA, "C", NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  Sonst=c(NA,NA,"A",NA,NA,NA),
                  Age=c(14:19))
```

Now I want a final df only with IDs and all information of the first df (as it is the target df)  plus the corresponding age information, if ID either matches with SIC, Ur or Sonst. I have tried dplyr and merge function approaches but did not come up with a proper solution. I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you confirm that the "D" value is missing in df2?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case where a subject is only present in df1 but not df2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `dplyr` and `left_join` with `tidyr`s `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(df1, df2 %>% unite("ID", SIC:Sonst, na.rm=T))
Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`
  ID Value Age
1  A     1  16
2  B     2  14
3  C     3  15
4  D     4  NA
```

or an `inner_join` if you only want A, B and C to show up

```
inner_join(df1, df2 %>% unite("ID", SIC:Sonst, na.rm=T))
Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`
  ID Value Age
1  A     1  16
2  B     2  14
3  C     3  15
```

Answer (score 0):

The convenient way is perhaps to do with the tidyverse family as was nicely indicated by **Andre Wildberg**. You can do it also using base R **merge()** function but in your case we need to create an **ifelse()** function to put all non-missing values of the three columns from df2 into a single column:

```
df2$ID <- ifelse(!is.na(df2$SIC), df2$SIC, 
                  ifelse(!is.na(df2$Ur), df2$Ur, df2$Sonst))
```

merge the two dfs:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by= "ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

Discard unwanted columns from merged data (df3):

```
df3 <- df3[, c("ID", "Value", "Age")]
df3
  ID Value Age
  A     1  16
  B     2  14
  C     3  15
  D     4  NA
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that some of the colums of df2 have more than one ID and I don't know which one has been used in df1. I probably should have made that clearer in the example, sorry!

Comment: Are IDs from e.g, a column are the same or different letters?

Comment: The values of ID appear either match with SIC, Ur or Sonst of df2.

Comment: Then this would be different story. My idea is to match the IDs of df1 with each column of df2 and then get the frequency of mathes. Then use the high frequent matchin ID to that of df1?
Would be good to post it as another question I think. Because this case here is also nice to have it .